# the pointer to a reference in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, vector

I saw some code in c++, which is a little bit confusing for me:

```
class Myspa {};

vector<Myspa> myspa;

Myspa * myspa_p;

myspa_p = &myspa.at(0);
```

`vector.at()` function will return a reference of the element, `myspa_p` is a pointer, so what does the `myspa_p = &myspa.at(0)` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> vector.at() function will return a reference of the element, myspa_p is a pointer, so what does the myspa_p = &myspa.at(0) mean?

When you return a reference, don't think of a reference as being a distinct type/object of data to which a pointer can point - there's just the pointer `myspa_p` and the vector `myspa` and no mysterious third "thing".  Instead, think of the reference as a way to grant access to an object (here `myspa`'s first element) in situ, without copying it anywhere.

So, `myspa.at(0)` grants direct access to the initial Myspa object inside the `myspa` vector.  Then, the addition of a leading `&` - forming `&myspa.at(0)` - simply asks for the address of that initial object - hence the address can be stored in the pointer `myspa_p`.

Answer (score 0):

This code compile..
Variable myspa_p point to the first element of the vector myspa.

myspa_p contains left-value of first element of the vector!!